# Mixing InputStream and Reader: process every line of text before passing on `byte` s

Tags: java, io, inputstream, apache-tika, inputstreamreader

I'm going to try and explain this as best I can, I have some InputStream, what I want to do is read the bytes of that input stream into a buffer, translate them with a Reader, and stop reading into the buffer when I see a newline. Then, I want to process the String I've just gathered, and sit tight until someone requests those bytes from me. If they request more bytes than I've got, I want to do this all over again.

Now I'll explain what I tried, and why it failed:

The first thing I did was create a class (lets say `Foo`) which extended InputStream and buffered every read byte to an array you pass it.

Then I have the main class, also extending InputStream (the eventual goal) which had an InputStreamReader holding onto an instance of the `Foo` class which was holding onto the original input stream, which I would read characters from into a buffer until I hit a newline. Then I process the line, and wait for read requests.

The problem is that InputStreamReader reads ahead, so it became impossible to tell when I had read out all the bytes from the current line and needed to read the next line. Note, also, I have no way to access all the characters InputStreamReader has buffered, and no way to tell when I approach the end of its buffer.

So, I'm very stuck.

If anyone was curious *why* I'm doing all this, its because I'm working with Apache Tika, which parses InputStreams, and I only want it to see a segment of a document, delimited by a key word.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't see anything here that isn't already accomplished completely by `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(InputStream))` and `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: I need to pass on the bytes after having read them. In your solution theres no opportunity to pass on the original bytes for the given line

Comment: Tika has mechanisms built in to do this sort of stuff for you -- why not leverage the tool that you're using?

Comment: Note also that you can use a [PushbackInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) with Tika in place of your original InputStream

Comment: Oh, I went through their javadoc and didn't see anything like it, I'll look again. If you get the chance, pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated! Also, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Here's a push: do what I'm currently doing -- dive into the source code to see what's going on, how the parses parse including the general principles behind SAX XML parsing, how the parser sends the parsed data do the content handler,.... etc...

Comment: Are you sure Tika supports this sort of thing? I see nothing in the documentation to indicate that it does :/ @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: It would likely require that you create your own parser, content handler and metadata, but I believe so.

Comment: You should wrap the input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` and use `mark()` and `reset()`.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't see how that would solve the problem @EJP

Comment: You call `mark()`. You wrap the `BufferedInputStream` in an `InputStreamReader`, and wrap that in a `BufferedReader`. You call `readLine()`. You call `reset()` on the `BufferedReader`. It is now back where it was when you called `mark()`.

Comment: @EJP sure, but after I've passed along how many bytes do I repeat this? It doesn't reveal how much of what was read was just the line I processed

Comment: I don't understand the question. It doesn't matter how much was read by `readLine()`. The position in the `BufferedInputStream` will be restored by `reset()`.

Comment: Heres the deal, I need to read a line of characters, and then, since Im acting like an input stream, read the bytes that correspond to that line. I can't read more bytes than that line has, because I need to make sure I actually want to read the bytes before I give them out.